# Matlab generated C code does not work properly

Tags: c, xcode, matlab, matlab-deployment, equation-solving

I would like to solve an equation (A*x=b) with Matlab in my iOS app. I generated the C source files and added them to Xcode. The strange thing is that for the same (A,b), I get different results in Matlab and in Xcode.

I use the default settings. Any suggestion?

Matlab:

```
%#codegen
function X = solveEquation(A, B)
    X = linsolve(A,B);
end
```

Xcode:

```
double* A_data = malloc(num * num * sizeof(double));     
double* B_data = malloc(num * sizeof(double));
for (int i=0; i<num; i++) {
    for (int j=0; j<num; j++) {
        double sum = 0.0;
        for (int k=0; k<9; k++) {
            double diff = powf(A[i][k]-A[j][k],2); 
            sum += diff;
        }
        A_data[j*num+i] = exp(sum/-2);
    }
    B_data[i] = A[i][9];
}

int A_sizes[] = {num, num};
int B_sizes[] = {num, 1};
double* X_data = malloc(num * sizeof(double));
int X_sizes[] = {num, 1};
solveEquation(A_data, A_sizes, B_data, B_sizes, X_data, X_sizes);
```

Comment: What results do you get?

Comment: Start by verifying that your A and B inputs are the same on both sides.  Don't forget MATLAB indexes column-major, and C indexes row-major.  Also, `powf` is the wrong function for doubles.  Use `pow()`, or even better, just multiply them yourself.

Comment: `B_data[i] = A[i][9];` is indexing beyond A's (initialised) size. (and, hopefully: 9 < size.)

Comment: It is not in the referred code, but I write out to file the values with printf, load it as csv to matlab and use it. Yes, column-major.

Comment: I.e. this is the first 5 value in matlab for X: -0.3449 -3.9745 -0.3449 -0.4534 5.8243 and this is in Xcode: -21.1767 11.835 -21.1767 36.1294 -20.1915

Comment: in powf you are right, I replaced it with pow, but the problem is still there

Comment: The generated code is simple enough.  Why don't you just examine it, and see if is a "solver" in the way you expect?   I'd also worry about differences in order of execution (you don't know what Matlab does when solving) and precision; is the answer different only in precision?  Is your problem well-conditioned?

Comment: I am sure is not well-conditioned, there are a lot of number with the same values. That could be the reason for the high values (21.17). By the way I tried already solve the problem  also with other mathematical libraries (GSL, Lis), but that was always something, singularity. Only matlab could solve it.

Answer (score 0):

How do the results differ? It's possible (even likely) that Matlab's numbers are more sophisticated that C's `double` data type. This might lead to differences in precision between the results.

Comment: The funny, that I write out the matrix from Xcode in %2.3f a reduced format (normally values need more than 3 digits precision), and after it I load to Matlab. And still, matlab can solve the linear equation problem better, than static library. Residuals are much smaller.

Comment: @Kukoda there's nothing strange in it, if the intermediate operations are more precise in Matlab than Xcode.

Comment: You are right, this MATLAB Coder is suck, for ill-posed problem, you can't use it.